# Importing bootstrap breaks Navigation bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

My project is running on vue3.
I have a Side navigation bar which consists of navigation links, it works well until I import bootstrap, which causes the icons to shift slightly and the buttons become smaller in size. I've tried the same with tailwind and the same issue occurs. The exact line that breaks it is the import of bootstraps min css file. (`import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`, inside of main.js).Below are screenshots and snippets of code for the navigation bar.

[image: before]
[image: after]

```
<script>
import NavBarLink from './NavBarLink.vue'
import {collapsed, toggleNavbar, navbarWidth} from './state'
export default{
    props: {},
    setup() {
        return { collapsed, toggleNavbar, navbarWidth };
    },
    components: { NavBarLink }
}
</script>

<template>
    <div class="sidebar" :style="{ width: navbarWidth }">
        <span @click="toggleNavbar" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
            <i :class="`${collapsed ? 'fa-solid fa-bars': 'fa-solid fa-x'}`"></i> 
        </span>
        <span v-if="!collapsed" class="logo">website.<span style="color: orange">club</span></span>
        <span v-else class="logo">w<span style="color: orange">w</span></span>
        <NavBarLink to="/about" icon="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass">Search</NavBarLink>
        <NavBarLink to="/plans" icon="fa-solid fa-tag">Plans</NavBarLink>
        <NavBarLink to="/fart" icon="fa-solid fa-user">Profile</NavBarLink>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
    :root {
        --navbar-bg-color: #0e0e0e;
        --navbar-item-hover: #1d1d1d;
    }
</style>

<style scoped>
    .sidebar{
        color: white;
        background-color: var(--navbar-bg-color);

        float: left;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        padding: 0.5rem;

        transition: 0.3s ease;

        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .logo {
        font-size: larger;
        font-family: Nexa;
        padding-top:15px;
        padding-bottom:15px;
    }
</style>
```

```
<script>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { collapsed } from './state'
export default {
  props: {
    to: { type: String, required: true },
    icon: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  setup(props) {
    const route = useRoute()
    const isActive = computed(() => route.path === props.to)
    return { isActive, collapsed }
  }
}    
</script>

<template>
    <router-link :to="to" class="link" :class="{ active: isActive }">
        <i class="icon" :class="icon"/>
        <transition name="fade">
            <span v-if="!collapsed">
                <slot/>
            </span>
        </transition>
    </router-link>
</template>

<style scoped>
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
}
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
.link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 0.1em 0.1em;
  padding: 0.4em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  height: 1.7em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.link:hover {
    transition: .17s;
  background-color: var(--navbar-item-hover);
}
.link.active {
  background-color: var(--navbar-item-hover);
}
.link .icon {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 35px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Is there a bootstrap component I can remove to make this function?

Comment: importing bootstrap is going to add a ton of additional CSS to your project.  by importing it, you're signing up for bootstrap's way of styling things.  it's obviously conflicting with your current CSS, so you just need to inspect your navbar in the browser and see what bootstrap properties are taking precedent and then you can add and/or update your component styling using `!important` to override bootstrap

Comment: Build a site with Bootstrap or don't. It's not a piecemeal thing.